# How to manually populate null values without using the 'identity' command in an SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created the table 'test':

```
create table test  
(  
    column1 varchar(10),  
    column2 varchar(10),  
)
```

and added the values

```
insert into test values('value1','value2')
insert into test values('value1','value2')
```

But now I need to create a column that will be a primary key, but I can not use the 'Identity' command because the control will be done by the application.

alter table test add ID int

How do I populate values that are null so they stay in sequence? Where as they are null.

result from '`select * from test`':

column1 column2 ID

value1  value2  NULL
value1  value2  NULL

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want to set column to IDENTITY in table definition and pass auto incremented values from the application? Please elaborate more.

Comment: Be wary of this implementation. Determining the "next" value in the application is a process fraught with error. You have potential concurrency issues and all sorts of other challenges. This is why identity is commonly used, it deals with all those things. Perhaps you should look at using a sequence. This would let your application "decide" the value and avoids the other issues. Often when I see people saying they want the application to do this it is because they don't know how to properly retrieve the newly inserted value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY column1, column2) AS RowNum FROM test
)
UPDATE cte
    SET iID = RowNum
```

Now check your table records

```
SELECT * FROM test
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

1. add a nullable column `Id`
2. update `Id` with a value
3. set `Id` as `not null`
4. make `Id` the `primary key`.

---

```
create table test (
    column1 varchar(10)
  , column2 varchar(10)
);

insert into test values
 ('value1','value2')
,('value1','value2');

alter table test add Id int null;

update t set Id = rn 
  from (
    select *
      , rn = row_number() over (order by column1, column2)
    from test
  ) as t;

alter table test alter column Id int not null;

alter table test
  add constraint pk_test primary key clustered (Id);

select * from test;
```

test setup: http://rextester.com/DCB57058

results:

```
+---------+---------+----+
| column1 | column2 | Id |
+---------+---------+----+
| value1  | value2  |  1 |
| value1  | value2  |  2 |
+---------+---------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Add temp identity column, copy values from this column to ID, then drop temp column:

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    column1 varchar(10),
    column2 varchar(10),
)

INSERT INTO #test
VALUES
('aa','aa'),
('bb','bb')

ALTER TABLE #test 
    ADD ID INT

ALTER TABLE #test 
    ADD TempID INT IDENTITY(1,1)

UPDATE t
SET
    t.ID = t.TempID
FROM #test t

ALTER TABLE #test
DROP COLUMN TempID  

SELECT *
FROM #test t

DROP TABLE #test
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, you can't create a PK with NULL values ([check MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189039.aspx)).

If you want to make your application to create your PK value, you have to give it at INSERT time or give some "Default" value(s) before your application edit it. The second option is dangerous for various reasons (trust your application to ensure unicity? how will you make a lot of INSERT in a short time? etc).